# .htaccess RewriteRule php redirect folder to another

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a folder test. If a person navigates to the folder test, I want the browser to display new.

The folder new doesn't exist on the server, I just want it to be displayed as new, which on the server is linked to the folder test.

This is my config (httpd-vhosts.conf):

```
<VirtualHost server.com>
    DocumentRoot "c:/www/"
    ServerName server.com
    Alias /new "c:/www/test"
    <Directory  "c:/www/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

So, to be clear, if someone browses to:

- server.com/test (the server uses folder test, but server.com/new is shown in the browser.
- server.com/ (the same as above => server.com/new is shown in the browser)
- server.com/index.php (the server uses index.php from folder test, browser shows server.com/new/index.php
- server.com/test/index.php (the same as above)
- server.com/test/folder2/index.php?variable=1 (the server uses index.php from folder test/folder2 and gives the variables to the php file. browser shows server.com/new/folder2/index.php?variable=1)

I have tried different .htaccess rewrites, but I can't get it working.

Maybe I don't have to use the alias?

***Don't just give me a link to the apache manual, because I've read it, but can't get it to work...***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `Alias` for this so comment out:

```
Alias /new "c:/www/test"
```

Then have these rules:

```
<VirtualHost server.com>
    DocumentRoot "c:/www/"
    ServerName server.com

    <Directory  "c:/www/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    DirectoryIndex index.php
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^/?$ /new/ [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+test(\S*)\s [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ /new%1 [R=301,NE,L]

    RewriteRule ^/?new(/.*)?$ /test$1 [L,NC]

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I'm in a different timezone than you I think, so sorry for my late reply. I'm testing it, but I think I'm still doing something wrong. I'll test it some more and then let you know. I'm getting a 500 error.

Comment: Yay, that did the trick! Only if I go to server.com, it doesn't redirect me to server.com/new yet. Btw does R=301 have to be there? That means a permanent redirect. And don't I need to add QSA (append query string from request to substituted URL) too?